# Pandas: groupby two columns, and look for the presence of a value in any of the other three columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having a really hard time understanding how to go manipulate `groupby` objects..

Here is a DataFrame that is reproducible:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 'Type1', 'Type3', 'General'],
                    [1, 1, 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'], 
                    [1, 2, 'Type1', 'Type3', 'Type2'], 
                    [1, 2, 'General',  'Type2', 'Type3'],
                    [1, 3, 'Type1',  'Type2', 'Type3'], 
                    [1, 3, 'Type1',  'General', 'Type3'],
                    [1, 4, 'Type1',  'Type2', 'Type3'], 
                    [1, 4, 'Type7',  'Type2', 'Type3'], 
                    [1, 4, 'Type8',  'Type2', 'Type3'],
                    [1, 4, 'Type9',  'Type2', 'Type3'],
                    [1, 4, 'Type10',  'Type2', 'Type3']])

df.columns = ['eventId', 'listingId', 'SeatPart1', 'SeatPart2', 'SeatPart3']
print(df)
```

gives:

```
    eventId  listingId SeatPart1 SeatPart2 SeatPart3
0         1          1     Type1     Type3   General
1         1          1     Type1     Type2     Type3
2         1          2     Type1     Type3     Type2
3         1          2   General     Type2     Type3
4         1          3     Type1     Type2     Type3
5         1          3     Type1   General     Type3
6         1          4     Type1     Type2     Type3
7         1          4     Type7     Type2     Type3
8         1          4     Type8     Type2     Type3
9         1          4     Type9     Type2     Type3
10        1          4    Type10     Type2     Type3
```

Now, I want to groupby two columns `eventId` and `listingId`. After grouping, within those groups, if there exists, a `General` as a seat type in ANY of the other 3 columns `SeatPart1` OR `SeatPart2` OR `SeatPart3`, I want a seperate column called `SeatFlag` that would have a `1` for those `eventId`, `listingId`.

So my resulting DataFrame would be:

```
    eventId  listingId SeatPart1 SeatPart2 SeatPart3  SeatFlag
0         1          1     Type1     Type3   General         1
1         1          1     Type1     Type2     Type3         1
2         1          2     Type1     Type3     Type2         1
3         1          2   General     Type2     Type3         1
4         1          3     Type1     Type2     Type3         1
5         1          3     Type1   General     Type3         1
6         1          4     Type1     Type2     Type3         0
7         1          4     Type7     Type2     Type3         0
8         1          4     Type8     Type2     Type3         0
9         1          4     Type9     Type2     Type3         0
10        1          4    Type10     Type2     Type3         0
```

A little more explanation,

in `row0`, for `(eventId, listingId) = (1, 1)`, you see that `SeatPart3` (The `General` needs to be there in ANY of the 3 `SeatPart` columns) has a `General`, so for every row that has `(eventId, listingId) = (1, 1)`, the `SeatFlag` column will be a `1`, but for `(eventId, listingId) = (1, 4)`, in no row, you find a `General` in ANY of the 3 `SeatPart` columns, so for every row that has `(eventId, listingId) = (1, 4)`, the `SeatFlag` column will be a `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groupby eventId & listingId, transform with function that checks for equality with `'General'`, and liberal usage of `any` reduce to a single series.

```
df['isGen'] =  df.groupby(
    ['eventId', 'listingId']
).transform(lambda x: (x == 'General').any()).any(axis=1).astype(int)

    eventId  listingId SeatPart1 SeatPart2 SeatPart3  isGen
0         1          1     Type1     Type3   General      1
1         1          1     Type1     Type2     Type3      1
2         1          2     Type1     Type3     Type2      1
3         1          2   General     Type2     Type3      1
4         1          3     Type1     Type2     Type3      1
5         1          3     Type1   General     Type3      1
6         1          4     Type1     Type2     Type3      0
7         1          4     Type7     Type2     Type3      0
8         1          4     Type8     Type2     Type3      0
9         1          4     Type9     Type2     Type3      0
10        1          4    Type10     Type2     Type3      0
```

Comment: Thank you. This one works perfectly for my LARGER dataframe in question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way

```
In [101]: isgen = df[['SeatPart1', 'SeatPart2', 'SeatPart3']].eq('General').any(1)

In [102]: df.assign(isgen=isgen).groupby(['eventId', 'listingId']
                                        )['isgen'].transform('any').astype(int)
Out[102]:
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
Name: isgen, dtype: int32
```

Comment: How do I append this back as a column to my `df`? can I just literally store it in a variable, and then do `df['SeatFlag'] = varName`?

Comment: I believe OP wants to group by first and then look for specific values.

Comment: @Abhishek yes you can.

Comment: @Zero, for my MUCH LARGER DataFrame in question, it seems your solution seems to have incorrectly flagged many of my `eventId, `listingId` pairs.

Comment: @Abhishek -- Interesting. I don't think it should. Without having a reproducible example, I can't do much either. This approach of checking isgen once upfront, would be much faster than other solutions generally.

Answer (score 2):

Each `groupby` element is a series or dataframe. So you want to look at whether 'General' is any part of the groupby element.

```
df['SeatFlag'] = df.groupby(['eventId','listingId']).transform(lambda x: (x=='General').sum()).sum(axis = 1)
```